# Is it possible to move triggers into their own file in an SSDT project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, triggers, sql-server-data-tools

I have a Visual Studio database project or SSDT of my companies database.

I have folders for Tables, Views, Stored Procedures etc and I was wondering if it is possible to have a folder for Triggers.

Currently Triggers are stored in the same file as the table definition and I would like to separate them out if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to put triggers in separate files. There is no automatic way to do this though so you will have to create these separate files manually.

Comment: The older VS Database Projects used to do exactly this. You'd have a "Triggers" folder or something similar, and all "CREATE TRIGGER" statements went into that folder. They'll still show up in the table design view so you can get to those files easily, but would be separate from the table schema script. I have several migrated projects that still have this as part of the structure. Just make sure they're set to "Build" and not "None" or they won't be pushed and you could actually drop existing triggers if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can do that automatically when importing the database but you definitely can create new separate file for the trigger and put it to any folder you like.

File location - does not matter, you can put it to any folder you like.